# How would I set up the fourier series for this problem shown below?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I have to the find trigonometric series expansion for a function $g(x)$ defined on $[0, 1)$ by the following formula: $g(x) = x(1 − x)$. I will show you what I have so far. [image]

I just want to know if the setup I have is correct with the coefficients.

Comment: The system of functions you have there is not orthogonal in $L^2[0,1]$. Namely, $\int_0^1\sin(n\pi x)\cos((n+1)\pi x)\,dx=-\frac{2n}{2n+1}$.

Comment: You could create the even periodic extension to (-1, 1). This has period Y = 2 so that L = 1. Then the $a_n$ integral would be 2 times the integral from 0 to 1. The $b_n$ will be all 0.

Comment: The period is given as $L=1$. Define 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      g(x), & 0<x<1 \\
      g(-x),& -1<x<0
   \end{cases}$$

which is an even $2$-periodic extension. Then, all of the $b_n$ terms are zero and the coefficients are found through

$$a_0=2\int_0^1(x-x^2)\,dx$$
$$a_n=2\int_0^1(x-x^2)\cos(n\pi x)\,dx$$

the integration can be simplified by the tabular method.

Comment: and then would you integrate bn be same way as you did a except you use sin() instead of cos()?

Comment: That was a repeat of my comment wit detail added. The $b_n$ are still all 0.